# Retrieving values from an Action callback in C#

Tags: c#, callback, delegates

I am trying to retrieve the return value from an async method using a callback mechanism as shown below:

```
public async void GetArea(double latitude, double longitude, Action<String> callback){

   String area = "";

   //code

   callback(area);
}
```

This is how I call this method:

```
GetArea(Position.latitude, Position.longitude, new Action<string>(delegate {
     //how do I retrieve the callback return value here?                   
}));
```

How can I retrieve the returning value from the delegate?

Comment: First of all, don't use `async void`. Second, what "returning value from the delegate"? `callback` is declared as `Action<String>`, which means `void` return type. There _is_ no return value. That's what `void` means. What do _you_ mean?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
new Action<string>(delegate { ... })
```

you can say

```
s => { ... }
```

and then the value will be available as "s". But it's a weird pattern in the first place. Instead of async void, consider async Task<string>, don't use a callback, and then use "await GetArea(...)" to get the result directly. This assumes that you're really doing something in GetArea that needs async.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class TestLambdaExpression
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Action<string> messageTarget; 

      if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length > 1)
         messageTarget = s => ShowWindowsMessage(s); 
      else
         messageTarget = s => Console.WriteLine(s);

      messageTarget("Hello, World!");
   }

   private static void ShowWindowsMessage(string message)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(message);      
   }
}
```